# Is a struct packed allowed to be used in ports?

Tags: system-verilog

Most of the tools I use allow it but one doesn't. I've read the specs, IEEE1800-2017 I couldn't find it.

```
module mymod (
  input   logic           clk,
  input   logic           reset,
  input   struct packed {  
                            logic [1:0]  var0;
                            logic [1:0]  var1;
                            logic [8:0]  var2;
                        } addr,

...
```

I saw some examples here and there, using even typedef structures in ports.

- Is it allowed by the specs? Where?

Cf. `7.2 Structures` and `7.2.1 Packed structures`

Comment: 23.2.2 - port declarations. follow *variable_port_type*.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! *A port can be a declaration of an interface, an event, or a variable or net of any allowed data type, including
an array, **a structure**, or a union.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A port can be any data type. (section 23.2.2) There are some restrictions on whether that datatype can be represented by a variable or net signal that interact with the port direction.

But I would strongly discourage the use of an anonymous type (struct in your example) and instead declare a user defined type with a `typedef` in a common package and use that typedef when declaring that port. That eliminates type compatibility issues when trying to connect unpacked struct and enums.

Comment: My struct is packed so that there is no compatibility issue with a simple logic bus. The goal is also to keep the logic short without having to create a new file or an extra typedef in a package for something used only once.

Comment: I know, but a bad habit nonetheless.

Comment: well.. hw code is full of bad habits, ala there is no critical tricky point, I'm fine. Thanks for notifying the best practice!

Comment: Especially when the struct has no meaning outside the module and is equivalent to a simple bus.

Comment: There is also the `alias` construct

Comment: For an input that's true! I've already asked a question about it. I'll try to use it more. Nevertheless that requires me to use a different name than the ports one.